# htaccess 301 redirect with different folder structure

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Thanks to all in advance I thought I had a handle on this but apparently not!

I am in the process of permanently moving a website to a new domain using a htaccess redirect

Old address www.example.com/home/index.php

New address www.example2.ie/index.php

I have tried using RedirectMatch 301 ^/ http://example2.ie/ but end up getting urls like http://example2.iehome/.......

How can I address this and am I even going about this correctly with the above?

Cheers

Comment: I think you might need to escape the trailing forward slash and possibly also add another forward slash to "close" the replacement string, haven't done this in a few years and don't have time to check the manual at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/home/(.+)$ http://example2.ie/$1
```